# Why is Read() not reading the frame range in CLI mode?

Tags: python, nuke

This is my script:

```
# confirming the project dimension resolution
projset = nuke.Root()
projset["format"].setValue("HD_1080")

# load video
foot = nuke.nodes.Read(file="C:/Users/Santosh/Desktop/MVI_8411.MOV", name="Nuke_Class1")

# select read node and attach write node to it
nuke.toNode("Nuke_Class1").setSelected(True)
wr = nuke.createNode("Write")

# specify the sequence path
wr["file"].setValue("C:/Users/Santosh/Desktop/nukke/nuke_API_###.jpg")

# connect to the first viewer, if many
nukescripts.connect_selected_to_viewer(0)

# perform the render, 50th to 140th frame
nuke.render(wr, 50, 140, 1)
```

I'm basically reading a video and writing out an image sequence.

The problem is, this script renders 1 frame 91 times, it was expected to render 91 different frames.

When I tried to investigate, I found out, the problem is with Read node. I found that *frame range* was set to **1**-**1**. Do I have to set the frame range manually? Because when I Read the same video file, on GUI, frame ranges are set correctly. This indicates GUI is depending on metadata, whereas my script is not, maybe?

How do I get rid of setting frame range manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem's contained in your Read node. You should assign a frame range manually:

**FIRST METHOD**

```
nuke.nodes.Read(file="C:/Users/Santosh/Desktop/MVI_8411.MOV", first="1", last="91")
```

or just without a first argument:

```
nuke.nodes.Read(file="C:/Users/Santosh/Desktop/MVI_8411.MOV", last="91")
```

**SECOND METHOD**

Or if you don't know the frame range, you can read in QT file automatically using TCL-style:

```
autoFR = nuke.createNode("Read") 
autoFR["file"].fromUserText("C:/Users/Santosh/Desktop/MVI_8411.MOV")
```

Also I suppose it may be possible with `sys` module's functions but definitely not using `ViewMetaData` node (in first method), 'cause it reads in only visible frame range when you use it in GUI mode or in CLI mode with already assigned frame range. The `metadata()` method returns a python dictionary containing the metadata for your Nuke_Class1 node, for example:

```
node = nuke.toNode("Nuke_Class1")
print node.metadata()
```